# How to search string approximate from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to find out a optimal way in order to find results similar to the input data. Take a look at the photos.

[image]

Comment: Try soundex function

Comment: I can see from your profile you have difficulty using SO. It would really help to look at the [help] and read the bit about asking questions here. Also, your image is mostly in a language that will look very foreign to most of the users here. Could you describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am sorry verry much :) My english very bad. Sorry @Jamiec. I just want how to do it. Can you help?

Comment: I can try, that is if I knew what you were trying to do - you've not described it at all. Do you know someone with better English that could help you write the question better?

Comment: @Jamiec I have no one can help, i just have a laptop and try to learn. I tried to find on youtube, but have no any video can help. So...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [SOUNDEX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189282(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select * 
from tblUsers
where SOUNDEX(tblUsers.Name) = SOUNDEX('Olof')
```

Another option is to use [DIFFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx)

```
select * 
from tblUsers
where DIFFERENCE(tblUsers.Name, 'Olof') > 2 --Where 2 is the threshold value
```

Comment: Thank, i will try it now

Comment: It's working :D thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

The T-SQL command you're looking for are quite possibly [`SOUNDEX` or `DIFFERENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) - most probably `DIFFERENCE`.

It is used to determine how similar two strings are - in the range 0 (very different) to 4 (very similar).

For example

```
select DIFFERENCE('Jamie','Janie') // 4
```

and

```
select DIFFERENCE('Jamie','Albert') // 0
```

So you would use something like

```
SELECT some_columns
FROM MyTable
WHERE DIFFERENCE(some_text_column,@input) >= 2 // change to fit your needs
```

A higher number in place of `2` will find only closer matches, with `4` being only very close matches.